# How to say "Save yourselves!" in Korean?

Tags: vocabulary

What is a natural way to say "Save yourselves!" in Korean?

Context: someone yelling this to his friends when danger is imminent, and they can leave everything and everyone behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

나와 얼른!

거기에서 나와 얼른!

다 버리고 나와 얼른!

신경쓰지 말고 나와 얼른!

죽기 싫으면 나와 얼른!

If they don't leave even after saying all the above, then you can safely assume they've chosen death.